# Resize Logo and Text Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I'm doing a site for my uncle and I have a slight issue.  When I visit it on a mobile, the Logo, site title, and navigation bar are all mushed together.

Here's what it looks like here.

How can I change this in CSS?  I've looked all over, and I didn't find any answers.  I've tried changing the @Media CSS part on style.css

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing:

```
margin: 20px;
```

That should create a gap between the logo and the title should be farther apart. Also if you could include some code in your posts that would be great.

Comment: OK, I'll add that code in there, thanks.  I'll make sure to add code in my next post!

Comment: Did this fix your problem if so please accept the answer that did.

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is currently down and there is no code what so ever, I can at least help you out with how to apply media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .<yourimg>: <your styling>;
}
```

This will allow whatever you are styling to be applied on screen that are LESS than 480px wide. You are obviously allowed to put in the desired width you want. This is but an example :)

You can read all about media queries [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Hope this helped a bit :)

// Marc Hjorth

Answer (score 0):

i use this:

```
<div class="col m12 s12 l8 offset-l2"> </div>
```

which sets the width of the div based on the size of the screen viewing it, making it easy to design a mobile site without having to design two separate sites.

for example, i'd make a container around certain area, set it as a row with a div and then use columns which change based on screen size

```
<div class="sections-container">
 <section id="our-vision" class="section">
  <div class="row">
   <a name="our-vision"></a>
     <div class="col m12 s12 l8 offset-l2">

     </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quick look at the website. 
There is an issue with an empty side bar that pushes the navigation down.

The sidebar with the following id:
id="sidebar-header"
You should try to disable the sidebar in your theme if you don't need it.
or you can add a simple css rule to your stylesheet to not display it:

```
#sidebar-header { display: none; }
```

to move the mobile menu you can edit this style rule in style.css on line 2795:

```
@screen and (max-width: 760) {
 ...
#access {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 3;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   background: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
...
}
```

Edit the top and left properties there (add some pixel values like: top: 70px; for example)

I hope this helps.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, where do I put that CSS code?  for both the sidebar header and the Mobile menu?

Comment: Sorry just saw your question now. You can add the css code to your style.css.
Did you create a 'child-theme' ? If not, it would be good if you do that later on. For trying it out you can go to your themes folder (usually _wp-content/themes/themename_) and just add the css at the bottom of the **style.css** file.

Comment: Maybe my comment is not really clear: the #access style rule you find in on line 2795 (edit the top and left values).
The rule for the sidebar just add at the very end of the file. (_all that in case you don't have a child theme_)